# How can I make the subject blend better with background?

Tags: post-processing, background

I am trying to blend the subject with the background in this composite, not sure what to do any more:

[image]

Comment: By "blend better" do you mean match better?

Comment: Please explain "blend better with background".

Comment: I think he's probably talking about the lack of bokeh here. It looks like the subject was standing in front of a poster or something. Try adding a blur to the background and see what that does for you. If you can re-take the photo you're using for the background, go take another but set the focus to only a few feet in front of you so you get that out of focus background. You could also read up on depth of field so that you understand why both the subject and background aren't usually tack-sharp.

Comment: Start by losing the shadow/outer glow effect around the man.  Think about how the lighting in this scene would look in real life.  Shadows aren't visible in the air, so that shadow/glow is killing the realism right off the bat.

Comment: are you talking about how to photograph the subject  or how to Photoshop the photograph?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. We don't know what the OP was really after, and 15+ months after posting, the OP hasn't bothered to even try to clarify.

Comment: @Caleb - I assumed OP was talking about lighting. Maybe incorrectly. *Maybe I also wanted an excuse to do some photoshopping on the lunch break* :-D.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if something like this is what you're going for or not...

[image]

It's completely possible to have a photo with the depth of field to have everything in focus. I chose to apply a 1.5px Gaus Blur and a 3px Blur to the image, and faded them in so that the 3px applies to objects further away. You *could* make the blur more extreme, but it's important that it fades to apply more to objects further away, and less to objects closer to the lens.

I also burned the model's side. The lighting doesn't look right - the buildings show very harsh shadows, and while it's possible that (if this weren't a composite) the model could be under a scrim, well, I think adding just a bit of contrast helps put him in the scene a bit more.

---

*My edits are a quick mock up to get the idea out there. If taking this to print/display, you should spend a bit more time than I did on making sure the subject doesn't have a halo around them from the blurring.*